# How to compare two 'long' value types in binary format (byte arrays)?

Tags: c#, serialization, binary, compare

I have massive (>5gb) binary files that contain long data types (among other data) in binary format at fixed offsets throughout each file. I have a long lookup value and want to implement a binary search algorithm to find the position in the file where the lookup value matches, is larger, or smaller than the nearest long value. The custom binary search algorithm is not the issue,

...but I am looking for help to compare two binary arrays to determine whether the equivalent long value is equal, larger, or smaller than a lookup value. Obviously, I want to get away without having to deserialize the binary array to long, else the question would be moot.

Can I compare binary arrays and determine whether the representative long values are equal, smaller, or larger without having to deserialize/convert from binary array to long? The solution should be faster than a type conversion and have a smaller memory footprint.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: I do not have an example simply because what I am asking is the first building block without which I cannot build the binary search algorithm.

Comment: Why do you need to do it without any form of deserialization? By deserialization here we're really just talking about getting the 4 bytes into a long value, it's not a complex or slow operation at all.

Comment: I doubt that you can make this any faster than actually comparing two longs. The cpu can do that using a single instruction.
It's highly likely any other solution would be slower.

Comment: because the file contains many tens of millions of data points in binary format and deserialization causes a huge amount of overhead.

Comment: My initial thought is that whatever you write is going to be much slower than simply grabbing 4/8 bytes and converting to a long using a explicitly laid out struct and then using normal comparison.

Comment: How about following :             Array.Equals(a.Take(8), b.Take(8));

Comment: He wants less than, greater than, as well

Comment: BitConverter.ToInt64() does the conversion from a byte array to a long using bit shifting, which should be the fastest way to accomplish what you are after. This should be quite fast.

Comment: I just tested the above and on my computer the conversion from array to long takes ~200 nanoseconds. And that includes the overhead of actually measuring it.

Comment: Try using an explicit laid out struct

Comment: I have code that seems to do the trick and seems to do what you're asking for. I will post it as a gist in a second, and want you to verify it before I'll post it as an answer. However, be aware that Stack Overflow is not really a "please write the code for me" type of solution, you should make an effort in the lines of what you want and ask when you're stumped about that, but in this case I think it's important to know the alternatives as well, which is a broader question.

Comment: Here's the gist, contains both the code (in which case you want to try LongComparer2), and the output from Benchmark.NET - https://gist.github.com/lassevk/263492b87cf0157b721653bed319ada9 - I'll unroll the loop in LongComparer2 to see if I can eek out a few more cycles

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, thanks a lot, I will take a look. I generally fully agree with your point re question format and providing some own work, in this case, however, it boiled for me down to an "it either exists or it does not" type of question. Please not that I explicitly mentioned that I am not interested in the binary search algorithm itself but I simply wanted to know whether a more performant solution exits to not just compare two byte arrays for equality but also larger,smaller.

Comment: Updated gist - https://gist.github.com/lassevk/263492b87cf0157b721653bed319ada9 - with unrolling the loop which might indicate that I could've done better when unrolling it, perhaps unsafe pointers would be better, but unrolled loop was slightly slower than just keeping the loop.

Comment: Also, as always when posting or reading benchmarks, buyer beware, I might have gotten something horribly wrong which skews the results badly, so you might want to independently verify my results.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, awesome, thank you very much, I find the way you benchmarked almost more intriguing than the routines themselves. I am quite surprised that the byte by byte comparison is significantly faster than the bit-shift in BitConverter, very interesting. I am not a developer by training and hence lack some fundamentals which prompted my question. Thanks again.

Comment: And then I thought, what about `Marshal.ReadInt64`, it should be able to just lift those 8 bytes out into a long directly. But nooo, it takes about 50 times the time spent using BitConverter.

Comment: By the way, I posted my code as an answer as well, an abbreviated and more conclusive answer than the gist, still linking to the gist though for all the nitty gritty details.

Comment: Did you remove your answer, as I don't see it. Would want to mark it as desired answer. Thanks again for this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My real answer is this:

- For good enough performance, use `BitConverter.ToInt64`.
- For even better performance, roll your own byte-for-byte comparison

Here's the second option, this seems to be quite fast. You will get out the normal -1, 0, +1 type of values you get from all CompareTo methods, which means that:

- a vs. b -> -1 means a is less than b
- a vs. b ->  0 means a is equal to b
- a vs. b -> +1 means a is greater than b

The code:

```
public static int Compare(byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
    bool aIsNegative = (a[7] & 0x80) != 0;
    bool bIsNegative = (b[7] & 0x80) != 0;

    if (aIsNegative != bIsNegative)
    {
        if (aIsNegative)
            return -1;
        return +1;
    }

    var a7 = a[7] & 0x7f;
    var b7 = b[7] & 0x7f;

    if (a7 < b7) return -1;
    if (a7 > b7) return +1;

    var a6 = a[6]; var b6 = b[6];
    if (a6 < b6) return -1;
    if (a6 > b6) return +1;

    var a5 = a[5]; var b5 = b[5];
    if (a5 < b5) return -1;
    if (a5 > b5) return +1;

    var a4 = a[4]; var b4 = b[4];
    if (a4 < b4) return -1;
    if (a4 > b4) return +1;

    var a3 = a[3]; var b3 = b[3];
    if (a3 < b3) return -1;
    if (a3 > b3) return +1;

    var a2 = a[2]; var b2 = b[2];
    if (a2 < b2) return -1;
    if (a2 > b2) return +1;

    var a1 = a[1]; var b1 = b[1];
    if (a1 < b1) return -1;
    if (a1 > b1) return +1;

    var a0 = a[0]; var b0 = b[0];
    if (a0 < b0) return -1;
    if (a0 > b0) return +1;

    return 0;
}
```

**Obviously** if you want to use this code you should write some darn good unit tests. Don't trust this code until you do.

Note that this method only works correctly when the data has been encoded using little-endian byte order.

If you need to work with big-endian byte order, reverse the byte order in the method, so that 7 becomes 0, 6 becomes 1, 5 becomes 2, etc. If you read the method it goes from 7 down to 0, this is little-endian. Make it go from 0 up to 7 for big-endian.

A signed 64-bit number, like Int64, is encoded in such a way that the 64rd bit (bit #63) denotes the sign, 1 means negative, 0 means positive. That's why the first byte being handled needs to be masked down to only 7 bits after checking the sign bit.

---

I tested the following methods:

- Using a struct with `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack=1)]` and explicitly overlaying a `Int64` field on top of 8 byte fields. This did, to my surprise, perform worse than all the alternatives. I'm *guessing* that all the shuffling of the bytes into the structs gives it more overhead.
- Using BitConvert.ToInt64, this, also to my surprise, performed much better than I expected so my advice is actually to go for this unless you find you *really* have a performance problem and this is the topmost bottleneck
- Byte-for-byte comparison, only going to the next byte if the first bytes are equal. This seems to perform the best

The entire code example, using [Benchmark.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/lassevk/263492b87cf0157b721653bed319ada9).

Here are the benchmark results for 10000 testcases, there are more in the gist above, including the full benchmark log:

```
              Method |     N |          Mean |         Error |        StdDev |
-------------------- |------ |--------------:|--------------:|--------------:|
    StructConversion | 10000 | 171,900.82 ns |   544.7975 ns |   482.9487 ns |
         ByteForByte | 10000 | 140,844.09 ns | 1,263.6139 ns | 1,181.9851 ns |
 ByteForByteUnrolled | 10000 | 125,728.87 ns |   377.4937 ns |   315.2243 ns |
   UsingBitConverter | 10000 | 130,397.25 ns |   497.1728 ns |   465.0557 ns |
```

**Note** that for 1000 elements, the ByteForByte and ByteForByteUnrolled results were reversed. I did use my computer while this was running, so this may have impacted the results. Buyer beware.

Comment: Worth providing some explanation of your code I guess, because who knows how longs are stored in OPs binary file. Maybe they are unsigned for example. And anyway some commentary of algorithm, even simple one, won't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a struct?

```
public class Program
{

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct ValueStruct
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public byte byte1;

        [FieldOffset(1)]
        public byte byte2;

        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public byte byte3;

        [FieldOffset(3)]
        public byte byte4;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public uint uint1;

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var value1 = new ValueStruct() { byte1 = 0x88, byte2 = 0x99, byte3 = 0xAA, byte4 = 0xBB };
        var value2 = new ValueStruct() { byte1 = 0x11, byte2 = 0x22, byte3 = 0x33, byte4 = 0x44 };
        Console.WriteLine(value1.uint1);
        Console.WriteLine(value2.uint1);
        if (value1.uint1 > value2.uint1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("value1 is greater than value2");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you already have the values in a byte array, this is actually slower than using BitConvert.ToInt64, see my gist here - https://gist.github.com/lassevk/263492b87cf0157b721653bed319ada9

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and for the benchmark results. :-)

Comment: I was surprised myself :)